# Получить код документа загруженного в iframe при помощи javascript

Tags: javascript

Нашел в интернете интересный код:

```
window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML
```

Судя по тому, что я понимаю, при его помощи можно получить исходный код документа, загруженного в iframe. Только у меня не что-то получается. Конкретно, не могу догнать, как сделать следующее.

а) Присвоить полученный исходный код переменной.

б) Как в этой переменной найти определенный фрагмент и присвоить его другой переменной.

```
<a href="http://forum.oooko.com/11109991" class="name" target="_blank">Алексей Новик</a>
```

Во всем коде, надо найти эту строку, и из нее извлечь значение href или чисто цифровую часть адреса страницы?

Как сделать это при помощи php - я знаю, а вот как выполнить это же при помощи javascript - я пока не знаю.

Опережу сразу вопросы в комментариях - другого способа, кроме как взаимодействовать через iframe, нет. точнее есть, но задача поставлена сделать именно через получение кода iframe, а обработку исходного кода выполнять при помощи javascript?

Comment: Если домен фрейма отличается от домена страницы, то вы навряд ли получите код фрейма.

Comment: Так, и что вам мешает сделать так `var test= window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML` ? То есть сложить в переменную код из iframe. А далее распарсить любым способом, например регуляркой. Ведь там будет строка. А строку можно ворочать как душе угодно

Comment: @Visman А чем это обусловлено? В Браузере-то можно посмотреть код фрейма.

Comment: Безопасностью. Вот можете посмотреть на какие ухищрения идут http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/210050/

Answer (score 1):

Пара выходов, как я это вижу:

1) Получить код из `iframe` в виде строки, занеся код в переменную, как вы и описали. Т.е. 
`var test = window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML`

Далее, раз в переменной `test` строка, то к ней можно применять регулярное выражение, вытащив все, что вам хочется и как хочется

2) Допустим у вас `iframe` имеет какой-то `id`, к примеру `myFrame` и ссылки имеют класс `link`

Из фрейма берем только самое необходимое:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame'); 
var frameDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
// берем только ссылки.
var links = frameDoc.getElementsByClassName('links'); // or var links = frameDoc.getElementsByTagName('a')
```

И далее перебирая в цикле массив с ссылками выдираете, опять же регуляркой, данные из них, какие вам необходимо и складываете куда вам необходимо и как необходимо

Оба способа сводятся в итоге в регулярному выражению. Правда в первом случае придется весь текст штрудировать. Во втором - чисто ссылки, что легче.

Точнее во втором способе уже можно воспользоваться выдиранием чисто ссылок
Опишу это через `jquery`

```
$(links).each(function(){ 
    console.log( $(this).attr('href')); 
});
```

Если Вы уверены на 100%, что ссылки будут содержать в конце только числа, то можно использовать `split`

```
$(links).each(function(){ 
    console.log( $(this).attr('href').split('/').pop()); 
});
```

Но лучше, конечно, регуляркой. Это надежнее.

---

**Дополнение, по просьбе автора вопроса.**
Если на странице имеется всегда только одна ссылка, которую нужно парсить.
`html` содержит ссылку следующего плана:

`<a href="http://forum.oooko.com/11109991" class="name" id="parseLink" target="_blank">Алексей Новик</a>`

`iframe` имеет `id="myFrame"`

javascript:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame'); 
var frameDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var link = frameDoc.getElementById('parseLink'); 

// ссылка содержится в link.href
console.log(link.href);
```

Подробнее уже просто некуда.

Comment: Ох, огромное спасибо! Я в меру своих скромных способностей попробую это сделать. Если получится - расскажу.

Comment: var test = window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML - вызывает какую-то ошибку, видимо при исполнении. Если включить это в код, то отказывает весь скрипт.

Comment: Какую-то ошибку... Конкретно надо. Какую. Не гадать же. Может быть забыли точку с запятой поставить. А может фрейма нет. А может луна влияет.

Comment: По второму варианту все проходит гладко. Получено object htmlcollection - это коллекция всех ссылок, которые были собраны из iframe. 
Теперь, как я понимаю, надо это вайлом прогнать весь этот массив данных и получить только ссылку которая имеет класс name.

Comment: Если на 10000000%  будет вероятность, что ДАННАЯ ссылка будет одна и только одна на странице, то достаточно ей присвоить `id`, например `id="parseLink"`.. И тогда достаточно сделать `var link = frameDoc.getElementById('parseLink')`...и уже оттуда достать аттрибут `link.href`.... я расписал для случая если этих ссылок будет много...... Так что же за ошибка с первым вариантом?

Comment: что-то у меня не выходит просмотреть элементы object htmlcollection  - links. Прошу мою неграмотность, можете привести пример вывода хотя бы одного элемента?
Насчет ошибок в первом варианте отпишу чуть позже.

Comment: @anj1817  добавил инфу. обновил ответ

Comment: Скажите, а нельзя ли сделать вот таким образом? Так как нет возможности установить id в ссылку. var link = frameDoc.getElementsByClassName('name'); На данный момент мне пишет undefined.
alert(link.length); - выдает 0. Это значит, что мы не смогли получить значение. так?